# Is the windows server essentials IP range limited?

Tags: networking, windows-server-essentials

I need to change the IP addressing on our windows server essentials 2012 server, as we are having VPN issues with people who need to VPN in, having home routers with the same IP addressing range.

So, i want to change the scope to something like 10.137.0.0/20, however, whilst researching this change, it looks like the subnet is fixed.

Is there some limitation to essentials that wont allow anything other than /24? Will i need to upgrade it to standard edition to allow the bigger host range?

I cannot seem to find any conclusive info on this from my google fu skills.

Comment: That's an absurdly large broadcast domain, but hey, why not.  No technical reason it shouldn't work.  What did your research consist of?

Comment: @quadruplebucky Research? As in, how did i come to choose that scope? Don't suppose you have an answer for my question do you?